# Dragging a JLabel over another JLabel

Tags: java, swing, drag, jlabel, mouselistener

I am trying to write a game and want to drag cards in my game.
I want to delete a label when I drag that lable to another label.

All the labels are created on the fly during the game.
Can someone please tell me where to read up how to detect if the mouseReleased event of first label is on different label

Comment: get location of the label being dragged, then check whether two rectangulars intersect. and show us what have you tried

Answer (score 2):

1. in the mouseRelease event you need to use `getBounds()` on the label that you just dragged.
2. from the Container class you can use `getComponents()` to get an array of all the components on your panel.
3. then you loop through all the components in the array to get the bounds of each component.
4. you can use `Rectangle.intersects(...)` to determine if two label intersect. If so, then you remove the second label.